# PermissionsEx prefixes are not working, but the permissions are

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I was editing the essentials config for my server, and I restarted it and all of a sudden pex prefixes aren't working. I didn't change anything in the EssentialsChat part, its all normal. I even tried reloading pex and essentials.

I put the permissions file through a yaml parser and no errors. When I do `/pl` all plugins are functional. I think one of the plugins did it, but I don't know which one.

My plugins are:

- World Edit
- World Guard
- Essentials
- Permissions Ex
- aAntiSpam
- Gods
- Jobs
- BOSEconomy
- ClearLag
- MCMMO
- Announcer
- Factions
- Lockette
- Vault
- EnjinMinecraftPlugin
- Multiverse
- RandomTP

Comment: Please post your permissions.yml.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this part of the essentials config (at the very beginning)

```
# Disable this if you have any other plugin, that modifies the displayname of a user.
change-displayname: true

# When this option is enabled, the (tab) player list will be updated with the displayname.
# The value of change-displayname (above) has to be true.
change-playerlist: true

# When essentialschat.jar isn't used, force essentials to add the prefix and suffix from permission plugins to displayname.
# This setting is ignored if essentialschat.jar is used, and defaults to 'true'.
# The value of change-displayname (above) has to be true.
# Do not edit this setting unless you know what you are doing!
#add-prefix-suffix: true
```

The comments are good explanations for each setting.

These are the current settings in my config, but mine are different because I'm using Herochat. My suggestion is to fiddle with these settings until it works. Not a great answer, but it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Multiverse overrides PermissionsEx prefixes. If you look into Multiverse's config there should be an option to disable it's prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

MAKE sure you do it like this

```
groups:
  aUser:
    options:
      prefix: '[prefixuwant]'
    permissions:
    - allmy.permissions
```

NOT like this

```
groups:
    aUser:
    '[thisISdaprefix]':
      options:
        prefix: add
```

also make sure essentials + essentails chat are both installed and running

also your plugins:

its NOT (used these fine with pex before):

```
World Edit
World Guard
Essentials
aAntiSpam
ClearLag
MCMMO
Factions
Lockette
Vault
EnjinMinecraftPlugin
Multiverse
RandomTP
```

it COULD be (not saying are):

```
Gods
Jobs
BOSEconomy
Announcer
```

try to remove ALL above plugins and see if it is fixed? (if first dosent work or dosent apply)

Answer (score -1):

Your need these 3 jars:
Essentals.jar
EssentialsChat.jar
EssentialsSpawn.jar
download install these it will fix it

Comment: Could be, the OP didn't say anything about the jars